# Como fazer para acessar um caminho padrão?

Tags: git

Como fazer para o Git 2.1.0 Windows acessar um caminho padrão (exemplo: `projetos wamp/www`), nas versões anteriores eu fazia isso fácil, `Git>Propiedades>Iniciar` em: `C:/wamp/www...` e pronto.

Fiz isso nesta versão atual mas não funciona. Como será agora?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se o git tem uma forma padrão de fazer isto, mas da pra alterar o diretório atual na inicialização do git bash

Criando um arquivo .bashrc no teu diretório padrão e colocando o comando abaixo, o git bash vai apontar para este diretório assim que iniciar:

```
cd /c/wamp/www
```

Este arquivo pode conter mais conteúdo e tudo que existir nele vai executar ao iniciar o git bash.